# My __MigrationHistory table is not hidden. Has EF Code-First been disabled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, appharbor, entity-framework-migrations

I've been reading about and beginning to use Entity Framework Code-First.
Its been working fine on my local machine (DefaultConnection), but it seems to have stopped working on my production server (a SQL Server add-on from AppHarbor).

One thing I noticed is that the __MigrationHistory folder is not hidden as a system table.

[image: Screenshot]

I've been using the method for automatic migrations described [on AppHarbor's blog](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/04/24/automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3).
This is my DatabaseContext class:

```
 public class DatabaseContext : DbContext {
      public DatabaseContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
      public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
          Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseContext, Configuration>());
      }
  }
```

I would like to get code-first working again on the appharbor database. Is there a way to re-enable it, or should I delete all of the generated migration classes and __MigrationHistory and re-create the database by temporarily changing the `OnModelCreating` constructor to use a `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` initializer? What would be a better way of resetting the migrations and starting them from the current written code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code First Migrations is just looking for a table called __MigrationHistory. It doesn't care whether it is marked as a system table or not.

In the guide you are referring to they are using a SQL Server CE, and if you are using that provider, Code First will never mark it as a system table.

On your development machine you are probably using a different version of SQL Server, so there you see it as a system table.

The reason it is marked as a system table in some databases, is simply to hide it. Migrations doesn't require it to be a system table in order to work.

You can read more in [this](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/27/code-first-migrations-making-__migrationhistory-not-a-system-table/) blog post by Arthur Vickers from the Entity Framework team, where he shows how to make __MigrationHistory become a non-system table on Sql Server.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue a while back when I wanted to implement migrations with an existing production system. You can set the is_ms_shipped flag on the __MigrationHistory table using the following T-SQL command.

```
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject __MigrationHistory
```

Answer (score 1):

See this article by Julie Lerman: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/ .It is not exactly what you're describing but maybe the "Getting a Migration-History table into an existing database" section can help you